# Eureka form - use variables to create .hidden predicates

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I'm trying to create a pair of ***segmented rows*** in **Eureka**, with the second row depending on the chosen cell of the first one.

I've managed to do it by building on the "hidden row" example in the documentation - and by hard coding my values. 
Here is what the row spec look like:

```
import UIKit
import Eureka

class ViewController: FormViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    form +++ Section("")
        <<< SegmentedRow<String>("firstChoice"){
            $0.selectorTitle = "firstChoice"
            $0.options = ["One","Two","Three"]
            $0.value = "One"
        }
        <<< SegmentedRow<String>("One"){ 
            $0.hidden = "$firstChoice != 'One'" //Row is hidden unless first choice is "One"
            $0.selectorTitle = "One"
            $0.options = ["1-1","1-2","1-3"]
            $0.value = "1-1"
        }
        <<< SegmentedRow<String>("Two"){ 
            $0.hidden = "$firstChoice != 'Two'" //Row is hidden unless first choice is "Two"
            $0.selectorTitle = "Two"
            $0.options = ["2-1","2-2","2-3"]
            $0.value = "2-1"
        }
        <<< SegmentedRow<String>("Three"){ 
            $0.hidden = "$firstChoice != 'Three'" //Row is hidden unless first choice is "Three"
            $0.selectorTitle = "Three"
            $0.options = ["3-1","3-2","3-3"]
            $0.value = "3-1"
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would really like to be able to specify the values through Arrays, so I could dynamically change them. I run into an issue when building the predicate function for the `.hidden` property.
I want to do this:

```
import UIKit
import Eureka

let ChoiceOne = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
let ChoiceTwo = [["1-1","1-2","1-3"],["2-1","2-2","2-3"],["3-1","3-2","3-3"]]

class ViewController: FormViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    form +++ Section("")
        <<< SegmentedRow<String>("firstChoice"){
            $0.selectorTitle = "firstChoice"
            $0.options = ChoiceOne
            $0.value = ChoiceOne[0]
        }
        <<< SegmentedRow<String>("One"){
            $0.hidden = "$firstChoice != ChoiceOne[0]" //Row is hidden unless first choice is "One"
            $0.selectorTitle = ChoiceOne[0]
            $0.options = ChoiceTwo[0]
            $0.value = ChoiceTwo[0][0]
        }
        <<< SegmentedRow<String>("Two"){
            $0.hidden = "$firstChoice != ChoiceOne[1]" //Row is hidden unless first choice is "One"
            $0.selectorTitle = ChoiceOne[1]
            $0.options = ChoiceTwo[1]
            $0.value = ChoiceTwo[1][0]
        }
        <<< SegmentedRow<String>("Three"){
            $0.hidden = "$firstChoice != ChoiceOne[2]" //Row is hidden unless first choice is "One"
            $0.selectorTitle = ChoiceOne[2]
            $0.options = ChoiceTwo[2]
            $0.value = ChoiceTwo[2][0]
        }
    }
}
```

This builds OK, but at runtime I get the following error:

```
2017-05-21 07:41:27.547 EurekaTest[74681:12894860] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7fa248e15f50 of class '_TtGC6Eureka12SegmentedRowSS_' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[_TtGC6Eureka12SegmentedRowSS_ valueForKey:]
```

I'm assuming `ChoiceOne[0]` doesn't get passed correctly as a string to the predicate builder, but I don't understand enough about swift and this construction to figure out a short cut.

Additionally, I'd like to be able, afterwards, to loop on the size of the array to construct a variable size segmentedRow.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can hide sections using [functions](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#hiding-using-a-function-condition).

```
    $0.hidden = .function(["firstChoice"], { form -> Bool in
                    let row: RowOf<String>! = form.rowBy(tag: "firstChoice")
                    return row.value != self. ChoiceOne[0]
                })
```